# SQL query to give distinct values from one column, and a count of distinct values from a second column

Tags: sql

Say I have a table like this:

```
column1 | column2
---------------------
1       | a
1       | b
1       | c
2       | a
2       | b
```

I need an SQL query to show the distinct values from column 1, and a count of the related distinct values from column 2. The output would look like:

```
column1 | count
-------------------
1       | 3
2       | 2
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you are currently using or at least an excerpt from it?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT column1, count(column2)
FROM table
GROUP BY column1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do a `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` with a `GROUP BY`:

```
Select    Column1,
          Count(Distinct Column2) As Count
From      Table
Group By  Column1
```